# When I try to add a dynamically created control to an asp I get a error

Tags: asp.net

When I create a control dynamically and add it to the page's controls collection, I get the following error.  What's going on? How do I add controls to a page dynamically?

```
Control 'ctl02' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

I'm doing something like:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    double total = (double)ViewState[cKeyTotal];
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Text = "hello world";

    this.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a form on the page. That control needs to be inside one.

Add a form:

```
<form runat='server' id='form1'>
    ...
</form>
```

And life should be good.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm working on the codebehind of a standard Default.aspx and it does have the html that you wrote above.  There's something else missing

Comment: I got it.  The problem was that this.Controls.Add() does not add the control to form1.  If you change the above code to have form1.Controls.Add() then everything is happy.